# SQL Query to find top item of each group and display details from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a query to be able to identify the top-selling items (quantity) per location and to display details about that item and store. My tables are currently organized as such:

Stores

| StoreID | Location | StoreName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | San Diego | Ralph's |
| 2 | San Francisco | Ralph's |
| 3 | Sacramento | Ralph's |

Products

| ProductID | Name | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Milk | Food |
| 2 | Eggs | Food |
| 3 | Reese's | Candy |
| 4 | Hershey's | Candy |

Sales

| SaleID | ProductID | StoreID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Therefore, the result would return:
Result:

| StoreID | StoreLocation | ProductID | ProductName | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | San Diego | 1 | Milk | 6 |
| 2 | San Francisco | 2 | Eggs | 2 |
| 3 | Sacramento | 3 | Reese's | 3 |

My current query I have sum's the quantity totals. I figure I must use a MAX to achieve the highest in each category, but am not sure how to bring back the additional information so it displays more than the count and StoreID. I am running this in SMSS.

```
SELECT StoreID, StoreLocation, ProductID, ProductName, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM STORE
INNER JOIN (Products INNER JOIN Sales ON Product.ProductID=Sales.ProductID) ON Store.StoreID=Sales.StoreID
```

Thank you for any advice on where to go next with this.

**Links to tables:**
https://freeimage.host/i/Q4XNp9
https://freeimage.host/i/Q4Xwk7

Comment: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad The expected result would be a table showing what is displayed in the "Result" table. In short, it would identify the highest quantity item per store and display some details about that store and product.

Comment: What do you mean by ``some details`` ? how many?

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  StoreID 
       ,Location    
       ,ProductID   
       ,Name    
       ,Quantity 
from    (
        select  *
                ,rank() over(partition by StoreID order by quantity desc) as rnk
        from    (
                select   s.StoreID
                        ,st.Location
                        ,s.ProductID
                        ,p.Name
                        ,sum(Quantity) as Quantity
                from     sales s join products p on p.ProductID = s.ProductID join stores st on st.StoreID = s.StoreID
                group by s.StoreID, st.Location, s.ProductID, p.Name
               ) t
      ) t
where rnk = 1
```

| StoreID | Location | ProductID | Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | San Diego | 1 | Milk | 6 |
| 2 | San Francisco | 2 | Eggs | 2 |
| 3 | Sacramento | 3 | Reese's | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B8yXBpQE)